# firebase Display Name is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to print firebase display name.
its showing after login. but after registrtion its showing null value. I'm using react-firebase-hook

```js
   const [userAuthenticate,loadingAuthenticate] = useAuthState(auth)
   const [update,setUpdate] = useState(auth)
   useEffect(()=>{
      const tokenUpdate = async()=>{ 
      if(userAuthenticate && update){
        console.log(userAuthenticate.displayName); // Showing Null
        navigate('/');
      }
    }
      tokenUpdate();
    },[userAuthenticate,update]);

  const onSubmit = async(data) => {
    const name = data.name;
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await updateProfile({ displayName: name });
    await sendEmailVerification(email)
    setUpdate(true);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the profile does not automatically refresh the profile in the current application. You'll need to [reload the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#userreload) after the call to `updateProfile`  completes.

Comment: can you please explain me how can i implement it? I'm using react-firebase-hook

Comment: You may have to update the user outside of `react-firebase-hook`, simply by [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) through the JavaScript SDK and calling `reload()` on it.